# Which Silverlight MVVM Test Project Type?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, automated-tests

When creating a test project for a Silverlight MVVM application, should I create a standard C# test project - aimed at the ViewModel, or a [Silverlight Test project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut/) aimed at the view, or (gulp) both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test Silverlight, you will need to create a Silverlight class library project ... you will not be able to create a "standard" test project, as Silverlight uses a stripped-down framework, and has alternate dependency requirements.  For example, Silverlight references mscorlib ... you will not be able to add this easily to a "standard" project, as this reference is controlled by project template.

ib.

Comment: Yep you are right. The standard project fell on it's knees straight away. It wasn't able to cope with any objects inheriting from UserControl. I suspect that more serious issues would have followed, have switched to the SL Test Project and all is fine.